# How do i access a class instance's parent in PHP?

Tags: php, inheritance, function, oop, instance

The only object oriented programming experience I have is from C#, so PHP is throwing me some curve balls I could use some help with.

I have a class I use for all my pages, the "pagebase" if you will. It handles the lowest level html structure. That class is inherited by several other classes. Those classes are the different page types the site has. Now: I'm having trouble setting a variable in the "pagebase" from the instance of the class that inherits it. In C# that would be no problem seeing as the class instance behaves as if it were the inherited class.

This is a representation of what I've got:

pagebase.php

```
<?php
    class pagebase
    {
        var $title = "No title";
        var $body = "<center>No content</center>";

        function setTitle($value) {
            $this->title = $value;
        }

        function setBody($value) {
            $this->title = $value;
        }

        function updateHTML()
        {
            ...
        }

        function drawPage()
        {
            $this->updateHTML();
            echo $this->html;
        }
    }
?>
```

std_page.php

```
<?php
    include("includes/pagebase.php");

    class std_page extends pagebase
    {
        function std_page()
        {
            ...
        }

        function updateHTML()
        {
            parent::setBody(
                "
                    <div id=\"main_wrapper\">
                        The page goes here!
                    </div>
                "
            );
        }

        function drawPage()
        {
            $this->updateHTML();
            parent::drawPage();
        }
    }
?>
```

index.php

```
<?php
    include "includes/std_page.php";

    $page = new std_page;
    $page->setTitle("Avesta");

    $page->drawPage();
?>
```

Now among other things, the biggest problem here is that NOTHING WORKS. The values in pagebase aren't changed even though I'm getting no error indicating the function wasn't found or run in any shape, way or form.

Someone please just inform me what I'm doing wrong - Thanks

Comment: I am confused, you are already using `parent::setBody`. Why don't you use `parent::setTitle` ? Is the any particular reason that you use "old style" PHP4 class definitions? Have you noticed that you have a copy&paste error in `setBody`?

Comment: Do you generate your entire HTML through PHP and then echo or return it? We recently discarded this practice in our project because of the many difficulties it causes - not able to see page's layout view in code editors like dreamweaver, editor's html tag completion suggestions of not working etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing first, never declare your properties using `var` keyword, please define its accesibilty using `public`, `private`, or `protected`.

Then when you want to access properties or method from the child class, you just need to use `$this` keyword. e.g `$this->title`, `$this->setTitle('title')`

Then there is `static` keyword when you define property or method as static you call it using `::` operator. e.g if you have `public static $title` then you can access that using `pagebase::$title`

Hopes it clear some confusion.

Comment: That clears the confusion right up :-) Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

This is a case of `parent` working in static scope, which is why you're using the `::` operator.

If it's inheritance, just try `$this->setBody` for example.

Answer (score 0):

I've made some changes to make the code run and fix up some issues. It's still not ideal, but it should work and be instructive...

```
abstract class pagebase
{
    private $title = 'No title';
    private $body = 'No content';

    public function setTitle($value) {
        $this->title = $value;
    }

    public function setBody($value) {
        $this->body = $value;
    }

    public function drawPage()
    {
        $this->updateHTML();
        echo $this->body;
    }

    abstract protected function updateHTML();
}

class std_page extends pagebase
{
    protected function updateHTML()
    {
        $this->setBody(
            "
                <div id=\"main_wrapper\">
                    The page goes here!
                </div>
            "
        );
    }
}
```

Here are the changes:

- I made `pagebase` [abstract](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php), with    `updateHTML` an abstract method. It    makes no sense to render a    `pagebase`, and the way a particular    child class expresses its    individuality is by creating its own    version of the `updateHTML` method.
- I made your internal variables `private`, meaning outside code    (including child classes like    `std_page`) can't modify or read them.    If child classes need access, you can    use `protected` instead. Those    methods accessible from anywhere are    `public`.  See [visibility](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) in the manual.
- When accessing methods defined in the parent, you don't need    `parent::`. That's only required when    the child has its own implementation    that overrides the parent's, but you    want to call the parent's version    explicitly. This can be helpful if    the parent method does some real    work, and the child wants to build off of that.  See example number 3 in [this manual entry](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php).
- If you're not changing how `drawPage` works, there's no need to    redefine the method. Since you are    overloading `updateHTML`, that    overloaded version automatically gets    used in the existing implementation    of `drawPage`.
- I fixed a copy and paste error where your `setBody` method actually    set your `title`, and you were using `$html` in some places where presumably you meant `$body`.

Comment: As I mentioned, the code in my question is only a representation of what my problem is. My pagebase class is easily 20 times the size of my representation, thus corrections typos on my code is quite redundant. Most of the corrections you are mentioning I fixed myself after Leonardys pointed out where I was thinking wrong. After reading a flawed tutorial I thought that the parent class was only accessible through parent::
That's why both extended class and parent had updateHTML functions. (Note: std_page.updateHTML updates the body while pagebase.updateHTML updates the entire HTML document)

Comment: But your point nr. 4 I was not aware of, so thanks for replying. I voted your reply up for that reason :)